# server side validation to avoid blank spam email

Tags: php

i sending contact form submission using phpmailer. i getting many spam blank mails to avoid spam mails i am trying to add server side validations but somehow its not working .
Below is the code i tried:

form.php:

```
     <div class="form-box">
<h2 class="form-heading"> How Can We Help? </h2>
<p class="form-subheading"> Request Your FREE Consult Below </p>

<form class="banner-form" action="banner_contact_process.php" method="post">
    <div class="banenr-field">
      <input type="text" id="Name" name="frmname" placeholder="Name *" required="">
      <p class='text-danger'><?php echo $errName; ?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="banenr-field">
      <input type="email" id="Email" name="frmemail" placeholder="Email *" required="">
      <p class='text-danger'><?php echo $errEmail;?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="banenr-field">
      <input type="tel" id="Number" name="frmnumber" placeholder="Phone No *" required="">
      <p class='text-danger'> <?php echo $errNumber;?> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="banenr-field">
      <input type="text" id="Company" name="frmcompany" placeholder="Company">
     <!--  <p class='text-danger'><?php //echo $errCompany; ?> </p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="banenr-field-textare banenr-field">
      <input type="text" id="Message" name="frmmsg" placeholder="Message">
     <!--  <p class='text-danger'> <?php //echo $errMessage;?></p> -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-submit-btn">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

banner_contact_process.php:

```
 <?php
 //print_r($_POST);
 require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

 $errName ='<p></p>';
 $errEmail ='<p></p>';
 $errNumber ='<p></p>';
 $errCompany ='<p></p>';
 $errMessage ='<p></p>';

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

// if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$name = trim($_POST["frmname"]);
$email = trim($_POST["frmemail"]);
$number = trim($_POST["frmnumber"]);
$company = trim($_POST["frmcompany"]);
$message = trim($_POST["frmmsg"]);

// Check if name has been entered
if ($name == "") {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    exit;
}

if ($email == "") {      
    $errEmail = 'Please enter your email address';      
}

if ($number == "") {
    $errNumber = 'Please enter your contact number';
    exit;
}

 if ($company == "") {
     $errCompany = 'Please enter your company name';
     exit;
 }


 // Check if message has been entered
 if ($message == "") {      
     $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';      
 }

$subject        = 'Enquiry submitted on Clicksplode website - home Bannner';
$userEmail      = 'poonam.katpara@atopdigital.com';
$mailcontent    = '<style type="text/css">
span{
font-family: Arial;
}
/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

 /* RESET STYLES */
img { border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
 table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
body { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important; }

 /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
color: inherit !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
font-size: inherit !important;
font-family: inherit !important;
font-weight: inherit !important;
line-height: inherit !important;
 }

/* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
 div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] { margin: 0 !important; }

   .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; background-color: #F1F1F1; }
    .ExternalClass { width: 100%; background-color: #F1F1F1; }
    body { width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-family: Arial, Times, serif }
    table { border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
    *[class*="mobileOn"] { display: none !important; max-height: none !important; }

    @-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .wrapper{ width:100%;  padding: 0 !important; }
    }    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
    .centerClass{ margin:0 auto !important; } 
    .imgClass{width:100% !important; height:auto;}    
    .wrapper{ width:320px;  padding: 0 !important; }      
    .container{ width:300px;  padding: 0 !important; }
    .mobile{ width:300px; display:block; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center; }
    .mobile50{ width:300px; padding: 0 !important; text-align:center; }
    *[class="mobileOff"] { width: 0px !important; display: none !important; }
    *[class*="mobileOn"] { display: block !important; max-height: none !important; }
    }
   </style> 
    <body style="background-color:#F2F2F2; font-family:Arial,serif;margin:0;padding:0;min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;">
   <center>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table width="600"  bgcolor="#fff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper">
                <tr>
                    <td height="20" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td align="top">

                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <img src="/images/logo.png" width="30%" height="auto" style="margin:0px; padding:0; border:none; display:block;" border="0" class="imgClass" alt="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="10" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>   

            <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" >

                    <table width="560" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="container">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" >
                                <span style="font-family: Arial;font-size:15px;color: rgb(35, 31, 32);font-weight: bold;">Enquiry submitted on Clicksplode website</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px;">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" >
                                <span style="  font-family: Arial;display:block;font-size: 13px;color: rgb(35, 31, 32);line-height:25px;"> Please find details below:</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" >
                                <span style="  font-family: Arial;display:block;font-size: 13px;color: rgb(35, 31, 32);line-height:25px;"> Name : '.$name.'</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" >
                                <span style="  font-family: Arial;display:block;font-size: 13px;color: rgb(35, 31, 32);line-height:25px;"> Number : '.$number.'</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" >
                                <span style="  font-family: Arial;display:block;font-size: 13px;color: rgb(35, 31, 32);line-height:25px;"> Email : '.$email.'</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" >
                                <span style="  font-family: Arial;display:block;font-size: 13px;color: rgb(35, 31, 32);line-height:25px;"> Company : '.$company.'</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" >
                                <span style="  font-family: Arial;display:block;font-size: 13px;color: rgb(35, 31, 32);line-height:25px;"> Message : '.$message.'</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="40" style="font-size:40px; line-height:40px;">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td height="10" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <img src="images/Welcome_Emailer_qafiyati.jpg" width="100%" height="" style="margin:0; padding:0; border:none; display:block;" border="0" alt="" /> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
         </body>';



   $mail            = new PHPMailer;

   $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Webmaster');
   $mail->addAddress($userEmail);
   //Set the subject line
   $mail->Subject   = $subject;
  //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
 //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
  $mail->msgHTML($mailcontent);
  //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
  $mail->AltBody    = 'Enquiry!';

   if(!$mail->send()) 
   {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

  }else{
  // echo "success";
  //------------------- SEND SMS --------------------------
 }

header("Location:thank-you.php");

 }
 ?>
```

i have print array its showing proper values inserted.
Please help me out. i am stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Message can contain some html with attribute `hiiden` and etc., or some unprintable characters, so you can't just check that message is empty after `trim`.

Comment: Your validation doesn't seem to do anything useful - you set `$err.. = '...` and sometimes call `exit` sometimes you don't.  If you exit - nothing is done with the message you've set, but if you don't exit it just sends the e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Add a CAPTCHA to your form. It can be as simple or as complex as you like. You could add reCaptcha, or even just roll your own.

Typically, before displaying the form you can generate a question and store the answer in the session. Then get them to type the answer in. Once posted, check the value matches that stored in the session.

Simpler than that however, you can also add `required` to your message form input to ensure it isn't blank, which was your original query. But you should still employ the use of some sort of captcha.

Comment: i don't want to use captcha. i want to learn server side scripting.

Comment: Captchas work server side, you need to script in PHP. If you want to learn, try this! https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-own-captcha-and-contact-form-in-php--net-5362

Comment: I agree captcha would be a good thing here. . OP could use invisible recaptha so user would not need to fill it. ..

Answer (score 0):

Check with PHP if email valid:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $errEmail = "Invalid email format";
  exit;
}
```

Add `exit;` also for message:

```
 if ($message == "") {      
     $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';   
     exit;   
 }
```

You could also do like this:

```
$error=0;
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $errEmail = "Invalid email format";
  $error=1;
}

//List here all other check too. .. Example:
/*
if(some validation isbad){
  $errorText = "Something is not validated";
  $error=1; 
}
*/

if($error==0){
    //send mail
    $mail            = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com', 'Webmaster');
    $mail->addAddress($userEmail);
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject   = $subject;
    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->msgHTML($mailcontent);
    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->AltBody    = 'Enquiry!';

    if(!$mail->send()){
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        // echo "success";
        //------------------- SEND SMS --------------------------
    }   
}
```

Comment: and for the rest?

Comment: @tejal Add exit also for message. .. But i would suggest to exit and redirect on error. ..